# Data base of exoplanets with common names to use beside Nasa Exoplanet Archive

Tags: exoplanet, nasa

For a project I am working on, I use data from the NASA Exoplanet Archive at
https://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/TAP/sync?query=select+*+from+ps&format=json

I take this json data down and import it to an sql database.
What's missing is the common planet name. The kind of name I find at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_proper_names_of_exoplanets.
I am looking for a table of common names keyed with the official designation so I can run a 1-to-1 match, e.g. "TRAPPIST-1 b"
As a bonus, it would be nice find a table witgh exoplanet type, i.e. Hot-Jupiter, super-earth, etc.
Thank you

Comment: That information is in the wikipedia table, in the form of a wiki link to the planet's page.

Answer (score 2):

As I commented, the information is in the Wikipedia table, but hidden in a wiki-link.  But with some text editing, one can extract it.

Trappist1-b doesn't appear in the Wikipedia table, and it isn't indicated as being an exoplanet that has received a proper name yet.

The database begins as below, the rest can be found in [this table](https://gist.github.com/zeimusu/3f775cae237b94fa8cd13b2a3fdfc687):

| Identification | Proper name |
| --- | --- |
| 14 Andromedae b | Spe |
| 18 Delphini b | Arion |
| 41 Lyncis b | Arkas |
| 42 Draconis b | Orbitar |
| 47 Ursae Majoris b | Taphao Thong |
| 47 Ursae Majoris c | Taphao Kaew |
| 51 Pegasi b | Dimidium |
| 55 Cancri b | Galileo |
| 55 Cancri c | Brahe |
| 55 Cancri d | Lipperhey |
| 55 Cancri e | Janssen |
| 55 Cancri f | Harriot |
| Epsilon Eridani b | Ægir |
| Epsilon Tauri b | Amateru |

Comment: Thank you, I'm just surprised the list is so short given that there have been about 5,000 exoplanets discovered so far.

Comment: Most don't have proper names, most probably will never have proper names. But note that the full linked list is about 145 names, not the dozen or so listed above.